# PHP: How to find US country by using IP range?

Tags: php, ip, range

I use some PHP script to detect US IP such as Geoplugin, hostip, ... but it make slow my page. So, can you tell me how to detect US country by using IP range ? Thank you !

Comment: Calling an external service takes time.  Looking things up in a database takes time.  What do you want, magic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the person posting it isn't interested in an actual answer, and has not narrowed the question to one of purely technical merit.

Answer (score 0):

you can find using this code

```
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
    $country_code = $details->country;
```

and you can get the php country array from this url :- https://gist.github.com/DHS/1340150#comment-1244239 and save into database. Now you just have one query to fetch the country name on the base of country code.

Answer (score 0):

the ipinfo.io was a nice idea! 
, now can do it with JQuery to deal with the user!

```
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }

        echo "
        <script type=\"application/javascript\">
            $.ajax({
                 url:'http://ipinfo.io/".$ip."/json',
                 type:\"get\",
                 dataType:\"json\",
                 cache:\"false\",
                 success:function(result,status,xhr){
                    alert(result.country); 
                 }
             });

        </script>
        ";
```